# Problemas com grid no Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Tenho esse problema. Vou ser bem direto. Imagens auto-explicativas.

Posso diminuir a fonte mas eu não sei a quantidade de conteúdo que estará no bloco. Então quero fazer um código funcional. Pesquisei algo sobre object-fit.

**Expectativa:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Realidade:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.col-6 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
.col-1 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
    max-width: 8.333333%;
}
.col-4 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
}
#page {
    background: #1b6491;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="page">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: você quer que a imagem fique preenchida em toda a div?

Comment: não entendi bem o que você quer?

Comment: Isso, que a imagem acompanhe o height da div. Pode até dar zoom, como aquela formatação do background(cover center center).

Comment: Isso parece ter funcionado aqui, mas no meu código acredito que esteja puxando outra coisa também. Pois a imagem ficou dentro do box, mas ela pegou 100% da minha tela.

Comment: Cara dei uma editada na minha resposta. Agora a img ocupa 100% da largura do container, mas não distorce a altura nunca.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc pode usar `object-fit` sim tranquilamente. Basta colocar o `width` e `height` da imagem com 100%, vc ainda pode usar o `object-position` para controlar o alinhamento do que é renderizado na `img`. *Só tenha em mente que `object-fit` não funciona no IE https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit*

Além disso é preciso colocar `overflow:hidden` na `col-`, para isso criei a classe `.col-img` como vc pode ver no CSS. Além disso usei uma técnica de position para fazer a imagem sempre ocupar toda a largura, mas sem distorcer na altura.

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor. Coloquei uma `section` com mais e outra com menos conteúdo para vc ver o funcionamento...

```css
.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  }
  .row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .col-6 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-1 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
  max-width: 8.333333%;
  }
  .col-4 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
  }
  #page, #page2 {
  background: #1b6491;
  color: #fff;
  }
  .col-img {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
  }
  .col-img img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
object-fit: cover;
position: absolute;
object-position: center center;
  }
```

```html
<section id="page">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-img"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="page2">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-img"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta.</p>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi iusto quam, dignissimos, totam recusandae repellendus iure cumque ab possimus esse eum nam architecto, dolorum consectetur ipsum laudantium distinctio. Maxime, dicta.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso, alterando o `height` e o `width` da imagem para `100%`, aí ela irá acompanhar o tamanho da div em que ela está inserida, [veja o funcionamento no CodePen](https://codepen.io/gabrielgoncalvesr/pen/dqVZod).

Só que dessa forma, se for uma imagem pequena, ficará distorcida.

Uma outra solução é determinar no `<style>` do seu `col-6` as seguintes propriedades:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Com isso a imagem acompanha o tamanho do texto ao lado, ela ficará centralizada na div, não ficará distorcida, mas não irá preencher toda a div, [veja o funcionamento no CodePen](https://codepen.io/gabrielgoncalvesr/pen/yxzPMJ).